# git pushes repository successfully but files don't show in the Git repository

Tags: github

I am newbie to git system and trying to set up git system (using git-scm) between my local computer (OS: Windows) and github repository. To test my git system, i have created a new repository, added a test file to it, committed, and pushed it to remote bare repository, all with no error. However, my test file doesn't show up on the remote repository.

[image: Git Bash Commands]

I have done all git commands on same bash. But file doesn't show up on the remote repository. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: what are the commands you used to push to thar repository ? , what are the git status after using git add . , please specify more debugging details

Comment: @  
abdo Salm. That were git init, git remote add origin <gitlink>, git remote -v, git add . , git commit -m "First Commit", git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

you have cloned your repository in cssims folder. so your new directory would be
"c/repos/cssims/cssims"

go to this directory and do 'ls' you will find your file

Comment: @ roh. Yes that's true. But the files don't show in the Git site.